# Why is awaiting on this faulted task not throwing the exception?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I *thought* I'd got my head around exceptions in `async` methods, and `WhenAll`/`WhenAny` behaviour when tasks throw exceptions, but:

```
internal async Task RunAsync()
{
    //...

    //one of persistenceTask, monitorsTask is going to throw an exeption
    var completedTask = Task.WhenAny(persistenceTask, monitorsTask);

    await completedTask; //I expect this to throw but it doesn't
}
```

.

```
//in a calling method later
var t = await RunAsync();
```

When `completedTask` has status faulted, I can see the inner exception in the debugger, but `t` ends up as successfully completed. What I *want* is the exception to get thrown by `RunAsync` - I know `WhenAny` does *not* throw if a task faults, but I thought if I `await` on a faulted task (`completedTask`) this *would* throw.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Take a look on this article of Jon Skeet: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/06/22/eduasync-part-11-more-sophisticated-but-lossy-exception-handling/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WhenAny` returns a task that never fails. The *result* of that task is the completed task.

```
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(persistenceTask, monitorsTask);
```